# Camel Restlet - Context Path Ambiquity

Tags: rest, servlets, path, apache-camel, restlet

I have Spring Boot Camel application where rest apis are exposed using camel-restlet

**Sample route**

```
@Component
public class AppRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    public void configure(CamelContext context){
       from("restlet:employee?restletMethods=GET").log("${body}");
    }
}
```

The App runs perfect ( `spring-boot:run` ). but am unable  to locate under which path the API is exposed. Log has no information.

Every API i hit returns 404. Log shows the route has been started. Under which path is it running. And how do I change it?

**Note:** Please dont suggest any XML based configuration. Anything that I can put under `@Configuration` would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the Rest DSL which is supported by the camel-restlet component like this

```
restConfiguration().component("restlet").port(8080);

rest("/rest")
   .get("employee")
   .route().log("${body}")
   .endRest();
```

And this route will listen to the following url
http://localhost:8080/rest/employee

EDIT:
I guess you could do something like without using the Rest DSL

```
    String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    from("restlet:http://" + host + contextPath + "/employee?restletMethods=GET").log("${body}")
```

The port and context path are configurable with the following properties

```
camel.component.restlet.port=8686
server.servlet.context-path=/my-path
```

The context path can be injected in the routeBuilder with

```
@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
private String contextPath;
```

Comment: I already made a choice. I cant change it now. reslet gives me a better control

Comment: Yeah I know, I have been to the same situation with Rest DSL and camel-servlet. Its more powerful if you use the bare component, but harder to configure See my edits for a second option

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html), the format of the URI in a restlet endpoint definition should be the following:

```
restlet:restletUrl[?options]
```

Where `restletUrl` should have the following format:

```
protocol://hostname[:port][/resourcePattern]
```

So in your case you could define the URI in the following way:

```
from("restlet:http://localhost/employee?restletMethods=GET")
```

This should make the endpoint available under the following URL:

```
http://localhost/employee
```

Which you can test e.g. in a web browser.

Comment: This is an elementery way. I cannot hard code hostnam and port name in all the API There should be a way to register the url context globally. A configuration may be

Answer (score 0):

Use the first of the three configuration methods described here:
https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/javadocs/2.0/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html

You should be able to customize it using the Component:
https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/javadocs/2.0/jee/api/org/restlet/Component.html?is-external=true

See in particular setServers() methods (or XML equivalent) to change the hostname and port.